# Android Emulator can access mnt/shell/

Tags: android, android-emulator, ddms

In my code i write some files in the destination `/mnt/sdcard/magnum`
When i run the app on a mobile phone i can see it through DDMS in the folder `/mnt/shell/emulated/0/...` but when i run it on an emulator i can see the folder magnum. A screenshot below. The shello folder can't be open.
[image]

Do you have any ideas why i can't find the folder on the emulator?